# Writing a recursive factorial function in x86-64

Tags: assembly, x86, amd64

The following assembly program works to print the factorial of a number:

```
SYS_EXIT = 60
.globl _start
_start:
    # run 4! --> 4*3*2*1 = 24
    mov $4,  %edi   
    call factorial
    mov %eax, %edi
    mov $SYS_EXIT, %eax
    syscall

.type factorial @function
factorial:

    # if it is the base case, return 1 and exit
    cmp $1, %edi  
    jne _factorial
    mov $1, %eax
    ret

_factorial:
    # if not the base case, set up the stack frame
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp

    push %rdi    # move the current value or n to the stack, 
    dec %rdi     # so we can pop it later and multiple by the factorial(n-1) function
    call factorial
    pop %rbx
    mul %rbx    # multiples eax (return of factorial) by previoud rdi (n)

    # clean up the stack frame
    mov %rbp, %rsp
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

Here is an example output:

> $ as factorial.s -o factorial.o && ld factorial.o -o factorial && ./factorial; echo $? 
> 24

How does the program look? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

#### Input Handling

At least at first glance, it looks like this doesn't handle the factorial of zero correctly. 0! is equal to 1, so fixing it is pretty trivial, by changing `jne _factorial` to `ja _factorial`:

```
# if it is the base case, return 1 and exit
cmp $1, %edi  
ja _factorial
mov $1, %eax
ret
```

Since factorial isn't (at least normally) defined for negative numbers, I've treated the input as unsigned. If you want to treat it as signed, you'd use `jg` instead of `ja`.

#### Register Usage

`mul` produces a result in `edx:eax`, not just in `eax`, so you normally want to clear `edx` before you start doing your multiplications.

#### Stack Frame

I would rewrite the function a bit to use an internal function for the recursion. That internal function would use a purely register-based calling convention to avoid setting up a stack frame for every invocation.

Using Intel syntax, I'd write the code something on this general order:

```
; when first called, input value in edi
; and edx:eax containing 0:1
; result: factorial in edx:eax
;
internal_factorial:
    mul eax, edi
    sub edi, 1
    jz  done
    call internal_factorial
done:
    ret
```

Then the main routine would be something on this general order:

```
factorial:
    mov eax, 1    ; prepare our 64-bit result value in edx:eax
    xor edx, edx
    cmp edi, eax  ; check for (either) base case
    jbe do_ret    ; if it's not a base case, compute the factorial
    call internal_factorial
do_ret:
    ret
```

Comment: Why are you zeroing `edx`? It is never read, only written to (by the `mul`), in the OP, and is otherwise completely unused in your version.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Clearing EDX allows the caller to actually get a result in edx:eax instead of only in eax. Depending on the prior state of the processor, this can also actually improve speed. The processor detects clearing a register (such as with `xor reg, reg` or `sub reg, reg`) so afterwards it knows operations that affect that register don't depend on its prior state, so it can execute the two sets of operations in parallel.

Comment: One-operand `mul` *overwrites* `rdx`, the previous state of it doesn't matter. It's `div` before which `rdx` should usually be zeroed